# Optimization of aggregate SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am running a query against a table in postgressql 9.2.

The table has a lot of fields, but the ones relevant to this is:

- video_id BIGINT NOT NULL
- day_date DATE NOT NULL
- total_plays BIGINT default 0
- total_playthrough_average DOUBLE PRECISION
- total_downloads BIGINT default 0

The query takes this form:

```
SELECT
  SUM(total_plays) AS total_plays
  CASE SUM(total_downloads)
    WHEN 0 THEN 100
    ELSE SUM(total_playthrough_average * total_downloads) / SUM(total_downloads) END AS total_playthrough_average
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  video_id = XXXX

# Date parameter - examplified by current month
AND day_date >= DATE('2013-09-01') AND day_date <= DATE('2013-09-30')
```

The point of the query is to find the playthrough_average (a score of how much of the video the average person sees, between 0 and 100) of all videos, weighted by the downloads each video has (so the average playthrough of a video with 100 downloads weighs more than that of a video with 10 downloads).

The table uses the following index (among others):

```
"video_index1" btree (video_id, day_date, textfield1, textfield2, textfield3)
```

Doing an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query gives me this:

```
Aggregate  (cost=153.33..153.35 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=6.219..6.221 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using video_index1 on mytable  (cost=0.00..152.73 rows=40 width=24) (actual time=0.461..5.387 rows=105 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((video_id = 6702200) AND (day_date >= '2013-01-01'::date) AND (day_date <= '2013-12-31'::date))
Total runtime: 6.757 ms
```

This seems like everything is dandy, but this is only when I test with a query that has already been performed. When my program is running I get a lot of queries taking 10-30 **seconds** (usually every few seconds). I am running it with 6-10 simultaneous processes making these queries (among others).

Is there something I can tweak in the postgresql settings to get better performance out of this? The table is updated constantly, although maybe only once or twice per hour per `video_id`, with both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: Your current index is not really helpfull for this query, but an index on (video_id, day_date) should speed it up

Comment: Can you post all the indexes for that table? Otherwise @dnoeth is on the right track.

Comment: Sorry, that is me writing the query wrong. The `day_date` part is BEFORE the `video_id = XXXX` part. I wrote it in this order because I was explaining it seperately. As you can see in the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` the index is being used. There is a seperate query for just the `day_date` field.

Comment: The "video_index1" index you posted didn't include video_id... You might also try to get a covering index, i.e. include total_playthrough_average, total_downloads and total_plays in the index

Comment: dnoeth: My copy/paste skills suck (I changed the parameter to make more sense in this context, but forgot to change it for the index).

A covering index may be a good idea, I assume this means it can get away with ONLY accessing the index rather than the records themselves, right? What order would the index need to be in?

Comment: It should be (video_id, day_date, other columns)

Comment: It looks like your table is already aggregated at the day level, and you want to reaggregate to the month.  But then why are there actually 105 records for September for a given video_id?  For the ones that take 10-30 seconds, do they have a lot more records than 105 that are being aggregated over?  Or does the slowness just indicate a general IO seize-up that does not depend on the exact query being executed?

Answer (score 1):

Your summing does not make sense to me. I think what you want is

```
select
    sum(total_plays) as total_plays,
    sum(total_downloads) as total_downloads,
    sum(total_playthrough_average * total_downloads) as total_playthrough_average
from mytable
where
    video_id = 1
    and day_date between '2013-09-01' and '2013-09-30'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/441e8/2)

Comment: The summing is correct. Examplified with 2 records with 10 and 100 downloads and 0.5 and 0.6 playthrough average:

My method = (0.5 * 10 + 0.6 * 100) / (1.1) = 0.59.

The thing is I want the playthrough average, weighted by number of downloads. The problem is not how I sum, but rather how to optimize it. I even tried just getting the sums (no multiplying or division) but it made very little difference in query speeds.

Comment: @ChristianP. Optimize is what I'm trying. I think part of the problem is the way you are summing, not that it is incorrect. Try my new version.